# Получение всех совпадений из списка

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть поле датафрейма dataset['genres'], там лежат данные в формате:

```
[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]
```

Мне нужно получить только список жанров, в формате [Action, Adventure, Crime]

Я использую следующий код:

```
dataset['genres'].str.extractall('name": "([A-Za-z]*)"}')
```

Но он возвращает только первое совпадение. В документации не смог найти про это информацию. Какие параметры использовать, чтобы возвращались все совпадения списком?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, с чем должно быть совпадение, и лучше добавьте в вопрос таблицу, как она выглядит, чтоб было понятно)
Вам нужно получить список всех жанров, или отсортировать таблицу, чтоб остались только [Action, Adventure, Crime]?

Comment: Step1709, Не совпадение, а вхождение.. Извиняюсь, неправильно выразился. Вся таблица тут не имеет значения, сейчас работаю только с этим полем. 
Мне нужен объект Series, в каждой строке которого вместо списка из примера (выделенный жирным) будет список в формате: [Action, Adventure, Crime]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если данные - текст, а не список, то можно либо использовать `ast.literal_eval` и далее работать со списком словарей либо воспользоваться `extractall` c дополнительными преобразованиями - группировкой и агрегацией:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(['[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]',
                '[{"id": 12, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Drama"}]',
                '[{"id": 80, "name": "Cartoon"}]'],name='genres').to_frame()
df['genres'] = df['genres'].str.extractall(r'name":\s*"([^"]*)"}').groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(df)
```

```
                       genres
0  [Action, Adventure, Crime]
1             [Comedy, Drama]
2                   [Cartoon]
```

Answer (score 1):

Я предполагаю, что поле в Вашей таблице выглядит так. Я сгенерировал искусственную серию, исходя из Вашего примера, повторив Ваш пример 10 раз:

```
import pandas as pd

example = [[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, 
            {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, 
            {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]] * 10
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(example), columns=['genres'])
```

Тогда Ваша задача решается применением `.apply` с генератором списка из списка словарей:

```
genre_series = df.genres.apply(lambda x: [genre['name'] for genre in x])
```

На выходе получаем серию списков с жанрами.